# Are their any tools or code available to evaluate cmip6 models (r or matlab preferred)?

Tags: climate-change

I would like to carry out a superficial analysis of a small number of CMIP6 models I downloaded from the ESGF. I'm thinking that a spatial correlation or Mean Square error between climatologies of historical observations and modelled historical would be useful. Are there any tools or open access code available to do this?